# XSD creation for additional attributes in tag

Tags: xml, xsd, wsdl, xslt-1.0

I have to keep a tag in XML in the way below:

```
<abc>
   <interaction operation="submit">
   <prop>
       <x>
       <y>
    <prop>
    <interaction>
 <abc>
```

The XML also can have this:

```
<abc>
   <interaction operation="update">
   <prop>
       <x>
       <y>
    <prop>
    <interaction>
 <abc>
```

I have created most of the XSD. Now, do you know how to define the interaction tag so that it can have operation = "update" or "submit" values?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and make  your XML be well-formed by fixing your closing tag: `</abc>` etc.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new type by restricting another type such as `xs:string` to allow only certain strings,

```
<xsd:simpleType name="OperationType">
  <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
    <xsd:enumeration value="update"/>
    <xsd:enumeration value="submit"/>
  </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
```

and then reference this type in your attribute declaration:

```
<xs:attribute name="operation" type="OperationType"/>
```